# ng-disabled to evaluate only on load

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have around 10 textboxes in a form page. I have the following condition:

1. Disable the textboxes if not permitted to the logged in user
2. Disable the textbox if permitted but has value loaded when the page loads(value loaded from service)

Below is the condition i have written to disable the textbox:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Textbox" class="form-control" ng-disabled="(Textbox != null && !isNotPermitted) ||isNotPermitted" required>
```

Below is the issue:
On load both the condition satisfies. 
But if i have the access and the value is empty in the textbox then it should be enabled and is enabling. Now, if i just enters one value, say 1 then again it evaluates the expression and making the textbox disabled.

How can i restrict the above condition and disabling only on load of the page.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: A. Please create a **working** snippet so it will be much easier for us to understand the problem. B. If I understand, you can add a temp boolean variable, which will flag if it's page load or not.

Comment: Please find the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8dZ3wRETZuk75SLA04pg?p=preview.
I have created the plunker for the first time. Let me know if this is not working for u.
(I think need to stop and run again to load the textbox)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to introduce a third variable.

Check the working plunkr here:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model="Textbox" ng-blur="ngBlur = true" class="form-control" ng-disabled="(Textbox != null && ngBlur && !isNotPermitted) ||isNotPermitted" required>
  </body>
```

In controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isNotPermitted = false;

  if($scope.Textbox){
    $scope.ngBlur = true;
  }else{
    $scope.ngBlur = false;
  }

});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/42csnMbxYkDk1CkNjSzJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If the textbox is enabled on load based on the given condition, then it has to be enabled all the time. I do not want to disable that again. This disabling condition should evaluate only on load for me. Hope i am clear